# Android - Passing an Activity object through an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I recently asked a question and one of the answers [(this one)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579459/7507743) was to pass an `Activity` object via an `Intent`.

Is it really safe to do that (memory leaks?) and how can you achieve that?
I tried passing it with `intent.putExtra()` but there is no method to pass an Activity.

Thanks in advance. I'm new to StackOverflow so if there is anything I've done wrong please tell me!

Comment: No, you shouldn't do that. What's your use case?

Comment: @manfcas Yeah that's what i was thinking. Here is [the previous question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579459/7507743). Thanks !

Comment: You should follow MidasLefko's answer for your other question. Passing an Activity through an Intent is a very bad idea. You want to either use `LocalBroadcastManager`, or you can use another library, such as `EventBus` to handle communication between two Activities.

Comment: @Advice-Dog Thank you so much ! I was almost certain that it was a bad idea but I wanted to be sure. Is there a particular reason that is a bad idea?

Comment: @Neïl The main reason you don't want to pass a handle to an Activity is because if you have any reference to it, the OS cannot clear out that memory. So you could easily have a memory leak, or a very memory hungry app. It's like passing a phone book to someone with your phone number circled within it, instead of just telling the your phone number.